# About verifying GPG4Win binary before using it

Tags: pgp

I've taken interest in GPG4WIN but I want to be sure that the binary file I downloaded can be trusted.

I do not have previous trusted release installed on a Linux OS and I need a trusted software to check if the Tails file I downloaded is ok to use.

So I checked every detail like sh1, certificate issuer, md5 and even some more and everything seems fine to even the file size but I have a problem with the timestamp.

The GP4Win website says:

```
notBefore: 2016-03-30 16:54:41 notAfter: 2019-03-31 16:54:41
```

and after download the file has:

```
notBefore: 2016-03-30 12:54:41 notAfter: 2019-03-31 12:54:41
```

And also the file was countersigned and I wonder if it can bad or not since I'm no expert at this but the info on their website seems to be the same BUT the time written above.

I need to be absolutely sure it is safe to use that program or if I'm better off using something else. I need to use PGP in order to send emails and verify programs if they can be trusted.

Comment: Check the timezone, it's probably just a display issue.